# Laptop fails to reboot when lid is closed

Tags: power-management

I have an old laptop that I'm using as a server, with Ubuntu Server 19.10. I leave it next to my TV with the lid closed. I have `HandleLidSwitch=Ignore` in my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

If I reboot my laptop with `sudo reboot` while the lid is closed, it will power down, and then fail to boot again. If I leave the lid open, the laptop will power cycle successfully.

Is there any way to fix this, or is this just how the laptop is designed and I'm going to have to live with it?